# Wordpress over HTTPS fails to load resources

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I've been running into some trouble loading resources on my WP installation after installing an SSL certificate.

Loading time has increased a lot and I have 30 errors with 'Failed to load resource: Could not connect to server'. Does anyone know how I could fix these?

www.melvinosenga.nl

Comment: Hi, your site is still using http for some js for eg i just see this “http://melvinosenga.nl.transurl.nl/wp-content/themes/rt_galatea/js/simplecounter.init.js?ver=58f22c9d... please update all urls

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/eECVi
I believe they're all using HTTPS? In my error log I can see it's trying to connect through https.

Comment: is ssl properly installed? try adding another html file and try to call using https

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider and they confirmed it is not a server-side issue: The resources are indeed loaded using the .transurl domain. My webhost suggested me to check MySQL for any values still left on .transurl and I have removed them from the wp-options table.

This does not resolve my problem and they double checked my database. They've told me that the URL is probably somewhere in my theme files or a plugin file so I checked the theme's functions.php file and wp-config.php. My theme however doesn't use functions.php to store this. I'm using Galatea from Rockettheme.

Comment: No idea where to look anymore. If someone is familiar with Gantry and Rockettheme I'd love to hear some suggestions on which files to check for 'hardcoded' URLs still left on .transurl.nl. I've contacted them using their community forums but they usually take a while to reply.